# Android 4.4.2 connect to Wi-Fi without internet

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat

I need to be able to connect to a wifi network without internet access.  On my lolipop android, I get an option "Use network as is".
How do I do this on Kitkat?

Comment: Device please? This should happen automatically, or you can force it to connect in the WiFi settings. This isn't supposed to be a problem.

Comment: Galaxy S4 on verizon.